# HTML5 Web Worker does not respond to message

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

Consider the following code:

worker.js

```
onmessage = function(evt){
    postMessage({data:"foo",id:evt.data.id});
};
```

master.js (embedded in some HTML)

```
function startWorker(count){
    var running = count;
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
        console.log("Creating worker " + i);
        var worker = new Worker("worker.js");
        worker.onmessage = function(event){
        console.log("Worker #" + event.data.id + " finished");
        worker.terminate();
        running--;
        if(!running)
            console.log("All worker finished");
        }
        worker.postMessage({id:i});
    }
}
startWorker(3);
```

Whenever I execute this in *Chrome* or *Firefox*, most times I do only get the following output:

> Creating worker 0
>   Creating worker 1
>   Creating worker 2
>   Worker #0 finished
>   Worker #1 finished

worker 2 is missing in the output, it never responds to the message. However, if I retry this for several times, a few times all workers respond to my message.

Do you know what my problem might be? I created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K3D5D/) to test this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is the variable `worker` and how it's used inside the `onmessage` function.

The `onmessage` function is async, and there's no special scope in `for` loops, so the `worker` variable is overwritten on each iteration and can't be used inside the `onmessage` function, instead we could use `this`, like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    log("Creating worker " + i);
    var worker = new Worker(url);
    worker.onmessage = function (event) {
        log("Worker #" + event.data.id + " finished");
        this.terminate(); // "this" will be the correct worker
        running--;
        if (!running) console.log("All worker finished");
    }
    worker.postMessage({
        id: i
    });
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/K3D5D/4/)

Comment: It works, but I still do not get one thing. The variable i is only used in a synchronous way, for constructing the object sent as a message. The callback does not use this variable. I guess that the integer value of "i" is copied in the object when creating it. Why do we need to create a closure in this situation ?

Comment: You're actually right, in this particular case it's not the iterator that is the issue, but the use of `worker` inside the async `onmessage` function that is the real issue as the variable `worker` is overwritten on each iteration.

Comment: Yep, the problem comes from the worker variable. When the callback is executed, the variable worker points to another worker which is terminated. Can you edit your answer?